# Error: The application which this project type is based on was not found

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-lightswitch

I installed VS2012 and tried to open a project that was developed using VS2012 as well by another developer. But I am getting an error message as below. I googled the error message and found most of MVC projects have same problem and found solutions to those. But mine isn't a MVC project. The original developer said it is a Light Switch and Entity Framework project. How can I start trouble shooting to find out what I am missing on my computer and to solve this problem?

[image]

Comment: Does the solution end up loading? If so, do you have any projects that say "unavailable"? Sounds like your developer friend has something installed that you don't. The "unavailable" project would give you a clue as to what's missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message indicates that the extension of your project is `.ls3proj`, which is the extension that Visual Studio Lightswitch uses.

Make sure that when you install Visual Studio 2012 (or when you change/repair), that this product is selected.

Answer (score 1):

This just happened to me too.  I was missing "Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools - Business Intelligence for Visual Studio 2013".  Once I downloaded that, I had additional Business Intelligence Project types when going to File -> New -> Project that I didn't have before, and I was able to open the Solution.

So maybe compare the project types you and your developer friend have listed when you go to File -> New -> Project.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the same problem, but I got similar migration errors when simply trying to build from a VS2013 command prompt after installing VS2017 (Windows 7).  My solution was already built, so there should have been no errors.  The migration errors seemed to somehow be related to .NET changes, perhaps due to the install of a more recent version of Visual Studio.  What fixed it for me was deleting the ComponentModelCache folder in C:\Users\your_user_name\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0 (or whatever version you're having trouble with) after closing all open instances of Visual Studio.  There "should" be no issue in deleting the folder, as it gets recreated upon re-opening VS.

Issues with the ComponentModelCache folder can apparently cause a number of odd problems: http://withmartin.net/how-visual-studios-component-model-cache-can-be-a-pain/