# Visual Studio 2010 migration to Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I have visual studio 2010 projects, that I want to upgrade to visual studio 2015.
I have installed visual studio enterprise 2015. When I try to open a visual studio 2010 on one machine, in visual studio 2015, I can open the solution without any issues. When I open the same solution in another dev environment, in visual studio 2015, I get the Upgrade error. When I check the Migration Report the error is:

'The application which this project type is based on was not found. Please try this link for further information: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=299083&projecttype=BB1F664B-9266-4fd6-B973-E1E44974B511'

I have searched the net for projecttype=BB1F664B-9266-4fd6-B973-E1E44974B511. But cannot find it. Can any one please tell me what is this projecttype BB1F664B-9266-4fd6-B973-E1E44974B511, and how to fix this issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: The application which this project type is based on was not found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15879816/error-the-application-which-this-project-type-is-based-on-was-not-found)

Comment: I don't think your story is credible. I suspect that the "other dev environment" isn't actually MSVC 2015. Certainly, there isn't enough info in this post to reproduce the issue your having. Screen shots and version numbers of MSVC might be required.

Comment: The project in question is a SharePoint 2010 timerjob; created in visual studio 2010. The visual studio 2015 installed on both the machines, is an enterprise edition.

Answer (score 0):

After doing some research, I found that the GUID {BB1F664B-9266-4fd6-B973-E1E44974B511} is for 'Visual Studio Tools for Office SharePoint'. I installed the SharePoint tools from Visual Studio, and then I could open the projects.